# ExtractTextWebpackPlugin always outputs file, even if there are no changes

Tags: css, webpack, commonjs

I have a project that bundles the client-side files using Webpack. We are bundling the CSS using the ExtractTextWebpackPlugin. The problem is when I edit a javascript file the CSS bundle always gets re-built despite there being absolutely no changes to the CSS state.

How can I bundle CSS but only when there are changes to the CSS files?

Extracted from my webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: 'css-loader'
    })
},
```

...

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(isDebug ? '[name].css' : '[name].[chunkhash].css')
],
```

Comment: Is the CSS bundle being rebuilt on watch? What version of webpack are you using? Also, what's the concern with re-building each time?

Comment: Yes, the CSS file rebuilds every time when running `watch`. We are using webpack `2.2.1`. If I didn't make any changes to the CSS then I don't want to waste time building it (incremental build time when running `watch` right now is approx 3-4 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever `ExtractTextPlugin` sees a `import` statement with `css` extension it will automatically extract the text contant of that `css` file **whethere it changes or not**

if you are using it to debug then use `style-loader` and `HMR(Hot Module Replacement)` for better experence something like this

```
 isDebug
        ? {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
          }
        : {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: "css-loader"
            })
          }
```

if you want to use current configration and don't want `ExtractTextPlugin` to build css file and you are importing them in your javascript file using `import` then somehow you have to remove `import` statement for css files when there is no change in that `css` file

and if you are adding css file in your webpack config entry section then it would be easy because webpack allow custom command argument and you can do this by exporting a `function` in your webpack config file insted of `object`

```
//webpack.config.js

module.exports = function(env) {
  return {
      entry: {
        main: env.includeCss 
                             ? 
                               ["./src/index.js", "./src/main.css"]  //build with css
                             : ["./src/index.js"] //build without css
      },
      .
      .
      .
      .
  }
}
```

you can pass env.includeCss by command argument like this

```
webpack --config ./webpack.config.prod.js --env.includeCss
//notice --env.includeCss witch will set env.includeCss as true
```

run with `--env.includeCss` normally and without `--env.includeCss` when you dont want to compile css file

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your question but I noticed you use `[chunkhash]` for extracted CSS. This will make your css name change even if you haven't change content in you CSS files.

Use [contenthash] instead.

https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/adding-hashes-to-filenames/#setting-up-hashing

> If you are using ExtractTextPlugin, you should use [contenthash]. This way the generated assets get invalidated only if their content changes.